# Regex - Match only first instance of brackets

Tags: regex, grep

As seen here: http://rubular.com/r/gPpvT4ppIN I am trying just to match the text inside the first pair of brackets, ie: (X11; Linux x86_64) However it continues to match another pair of brackets later in the line as well. I am using grep.

The regular expression I have tried so far:

```
\(+?.+?\)
```

The line:

```
"Mozilla/4.5 (X1; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, Gecko) Qt/4.8.1 Safari/53"
```

The target:

```
(X11; Linux x86_64)
```

not also

```
(KHTML, Gecko)
```

I have tried to use a lazy match like '.*?' but am unsure where to put it.

Comment: armnotstrong i have tried .*? as it says in that post, however I cannot figure out how to use it appropriately.

Comment: Grep is the wrong tool. The first sentence in the man page: "grep prints lines that contain a match for a pattern." Since it sounds like you're trying to extract text within lines, you'll need another tool. Look at awk, perl, perhaps sed and others.

Comment: sorry for the misleading, they are not the same, have removed the flag, very sorry, which language do you use, cause this should be a language specific solution? as Python have a matched group to get all the matched groups of the regex search

Comment: im in a situation where im forced to be using grep

Comment: @IvanLendl as commented by Gene grep will not be a suitable tool for this try other tools like awk for help

Answer (score 3):

For python its something like:

```
string = "Mozilla/4.5 (X1; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, Gecko) Qt/4.8.1 Safari/53"

search = re.search(r"\((.*?)\)", string)
text = string[search.start():search.end()]
```

So (.*?) matches everything in between, and you need to put that between two bracket. However, for bracket, you need to do "\(" and "\)"

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
s='Mozilla/4.5 (X1; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, Gecko) Qt/4.8.1 Safari/53'
echo $s | grep -o '([^()]*)' | head -1
```

Output: `(X1; Linux x86_64)`. See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/jaE1gt).

**Details**

- `grep -o '([^()]*)'` -  `-o` option makes the program return all matches (not lines where a match occurred), and the following patterns are searched for:

  - `(` - a literal `(` char (since it is a POSIX BRE pattern, the unescaped `(` matches a literal round bracket)
  - `[^()]*` - a negated bracket expression matching 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `)` - a literal `)` char
- `head -1` - only fetches the first match.

Answer (score 2):

For Javascript:

```
const re = /\((.*?)\)/;
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.5 (X1; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, Gecko) Qt/4.8.1 Safari/53';
const platformA = userAgent.match(re)[0]; // (X1; Linux x86_64)
const platformB = userAgent.match(re)[1]; //  X1; Linux x86_64
```