# Windows Batch: Grep text in first quotation marks

Tags: batch-file, grep, quotation-marks

I've got a text file with following line:

```
17,60,"10 Ursae Majoris",0.03125,34.90625,-39.09375,0,0,176,None,5,None,64,Anarchy,10,None,,,,0,1678643440,1678643440,"10 Ursae Majoris",,,3,Common,2415659059555
```

and need to get the name inside the first quotation marks, so
`10 Ursae Majoris`
the second quotation marks should be ignored.

my code can't work, as I'm on Windows Batch and not on linux:

```
echo off

for /f "delims=," %%i in (systems.txt) do echo %%i | grep -o '([^""]*)' | head -1
```

what is the Windows Batch equivalent?
Many thanks.

searched and found [Regex - Match only first instance of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474170/regex-match-only-first-instance-of-brackets)

Comment: Is this what you mean? ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("systems.txt") Do @Echo %%G```

Comment: use powershell instead which has builtin capability to deal with json, csv, xml... directly: `(cat file | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'a','b','c').c`. For example `(echo '17,60,"10 Ursae Majoris",0.03125,34.90625,-39.09375,0,0,176,None,5,None,64,Anarchy,10,None,,,,0,1678643440,1678643440,"10 Ursae Majoris",,,3,Common,2415659059555' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'a', 'b', 'c').c`

Comment: `for /f "tokens-3delims=," %%i in (systems.txt) do echo %%~i` Assuming that the required string is always the third comma-separated token

Comment: That should be `tokens=3` of course...

Comment: This works: `for /F "delims=" %%i in (systems.txt) do set "line=%%i"` line `set "line=%line:*"=%"` line `set "name=%line:"=" & rem "%"`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I get a "cannot be processed syntactically at this point" with every one of your for-loops. Do you have an idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my `systems.txt` test file:

```
17,60,"10 Ursae Majoris",0.03125,34.90625,-39.09375,0,0,176,None,5,None,64,Anarchy,10,None,,,,0,1678643440,1678643440,"10 Ursae Majoris",,,3,Common,2415659059555
```

This is my Batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "delims=" %%a in (systems.txt) do set "line=%%a"
set "line=%line:*"=%"
set "name=%line:"=" & rem "%"
echo %name%
```

This is the output:

```
10 Ursae Majoris
```